# angularjs nested ng-repeat scopes with custom directives

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an angular project using angularjs 1.3.7 and cannot figure out why an object I'm passing with an attribute from a parent to a child (each with their own isolated scopes), will not pass properly. Logging to the console from the child directive will show this object as undefined whereas logging to the console from the parent will show the object as intended. Below is a simplified version of what I'm currently working with.

Main View Template:

```
<parent-directive>
```

Parent Directive:

```
HTML:
<div>
  <div ng-repeat="foo in parentCtrl.foos">
    <child-directive foo="foo" bar="parentCtrl.bar"></child-directive>
  </div>
</div>

javascript:
angular
  .module('parentDirectiveModule', [])
  .directive('parentDirective', function() {   
    var parentDirectiveCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope){
      var parentCtrl = this;
      parentCtrl.foos = [
        {'name': 'foo1', 'id': '1'},
        {'name': 'foo2', 'id': '2'}
      ];
      parentCtrl.bar = {'property': 'name'};
    return {
      scope: {},
      templateUrl: '../parentDirective.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      controller: parentDirectiveCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'parentCtrl',
      bindToController: true
    }
  }];
```

Child Directive:

```
HTML:
<div>
  <span>{{childCtrl.foo}}</span>
  <button ng-click="childCtrl.editBar()">{{childCtrl.bar.property}}</button>
</div>

javascript:
angular
  .module('childDirectiveModule', [])
  .directive('childDirective', function() {   
    var childDirectiveCtrl = ['$scope', function($scope){
      var childCtrl = this;
      console.log(childCtrl.foo);
      console.log(childCtrl.bar);
      childCtrl.editBar = function() {
        // update bar and reflect in the parent controller
      };
    return {
      scope: {
        foo: '=',
        bar: '='
      },
      templateUrl: '../childDirective.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: false,
      controller: childDirectiveCtrl,
      controllerAs: 'childCtrl',
      bindToController: true
    }
  }];
```

Using the above code, the console log on childCtrl.foo returns the foo object as expected, but the childCtrl.bar returns as undefined.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: fixed a spelling

EDIT EDIT: closed an open " and changed bar to parentCtrl.bar on

Comment: the StackOverflow code highlights reveals a missing closing quote in the HTML of childDirective. is this in the code itself?

Comment: Also, I think ng-repeat creates a child scope so try using `bar="parentCtrl.bar"` in parentDirective's HTML

Comment: Thanks for the help. This code is just representative of the structure of the angular project.  jmustonen mentioned the same thing about using the dot notation to pass the attribute parameter in the child-directive. I actually already do that.

I gave additional information in my response to jmustonen 's answer which might shed more light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `bar="bar"` assignment to this:

```
<div>
    <div ng-repeat="foo in parentCtrl.foos">
        <child-directive foo="foo" bar="parentCtrl.bar"></child-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

At least with a quick glance that might be the cause for your problem, `bar` being genuinely `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In the original code I have bar="parentCtrl.bar", but I mistyped it in my post.  Unfortunately, when I console.log childCtrl.bar in the child-directive controller, I still get an undefined for every entry in the ng-repeat.

I'm not sure if it helps, but I just added a link function and I was able to see that contents of the directive for the parentCtrl under scope.  Here is the link function within the child-directive: `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {console.log(scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.parentCtrl.bar)}` and I the log printed the object as expected.

Comment: Its may also be worth noting, that the link function `link: function(scope, element, attrs) {console.log(attrs.bar)}` results in undefined, but `link: function(scope,element,attrs){console.log(attrs)}` gives an object of $$element, $attr object with the value of {"bar": "bar"}, and the property bar with a value of "parentCtrl.bar".

If it helps at all, my goal is to be able to edit the bar object from any one of the child-directives inside of ng-repeat.

Comment: In that case please try to reproduce your problem in a plunk or jsfiddle, for example. There were a couple of problems with your simplified version (syntax errors in controller code - for example misplaced `]);`s in the end of controllers - and missing module dependencies) but I got it working as I believe it should (`parentCtrl.bar` showing up correctly in `childDirective`, editing `childCtrl.bar` reflecting the changes also to `parentCtrl` etc) in this plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/PWbVaDmr5KGRZRwm5lJE?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help.  So it looks like my issue is actually related to the way angular handles camel-case conversions when copying an attribute into an isolated scope.  On the child-directive, I have the property bar="parentCtrl.bar".  In actuality, I have a camel case name for this attribute which is something more akin to fooBar="parentCtrl.bar".  In the declaration of the isolated scope, angular will pass this attibute as foobar and not as the fooBar I was expecting.  As a result, every time I console logged childCtrl.fooBar, I would get undefined.

To fix this problem, I changed the attribute name to foo-bar.  Angular did not need to do any more conversions and the object passed through as expected.